# How to change pandas table data arrangement?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to change the arrangement of this table:

```
import pandas as pd

original_dict = {
    "group A" : [10,9,11],
    "group B" :[23,42,56]
}

original_df = pd.DataFrame(original_dict)
original_df
```

Here is the desired output:

| Value | Group Type |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | group A |
| 9 | group A |
| 11 | group A |
| 23 | group B |
| 42 | group B |
| 56 | group B |

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas Melt function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

```
df = pd.melt(original_df)
df.columns=['Group Type', 'Value']
df
```

```
Group Type      Value
group A         10
group A         9
group A         11
group B         23
group B         42
group B         56
```